# JavaFX comunicación entre ventanas que no funciona

Tags: java, javafx, interfaz-gráfica

Abro una ventana hija desde la ventana padre.
Codigo de la ventana padre:

```
@FXML
    void ModificarProducto(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(VistaAdminController.class.getResource("/rfaprez/proyectodam_rfaprez/VistasAdmin/ModificarProduto.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("   MODIFICAR PRODUCTO -- SCRAT SYSTEM");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        ModificarProductoController mpc = fxmlLoader.getController();
        mpc.setStage(stage);

        stage.show();
}
```

Y el código de la ventana Hija:

```
      public void setStage(Stage s) {
           this.Stage = s;
      }
      @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    
            try {
                cargarProductos();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                c.mostrarVentanaEmer(e + e.getMessage(), ERROR);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stage = (javafx.stage.Stage) myAnchorPane_ModifProducto.getScene().getWindow();
            Stage s = stage;
    
            s.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> System.out.println("me salgo"));
           
        }
```

Quiero implementar el evento de cerrar la ventana hija, y para ello necesito el objeto Stage que he instanciado en la ventana padre. El método setStage me debería permitir obtener la dirección a dicho objeto Stage pero sin embargo no es así y obtengo un NullPointerException porque el objeto Stage en la ventana hija es NULL entonces hay algo que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias

Comment: veo que tiene un setter que tiene por parámetro un objeto Stage  . Al parececer la clase hija tiene un campo de clase Stage . pero no lo puedo ayudar dado que su  código no lo puedo reproducir